# Implement priorities (high, medium, low) in AWS SQS in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, queue, amazon-sqs, lumen

How to pass priorities (high, medium, low) in AWS SQS in Lumen PHP.

**Packages**

```
"php": "^7.3|^8.0",
"aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.158",
"laravel/lumen-framework": "^8.0"
```

**queqe.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sqs'),

    'connections' => [
        'sqs' => [
            'driver' => 'sqs',
            'key' => 'key',
            'secret' => 'secret',
            'prefix' => 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1234567891452',
            'queue' => '',
            'suffix' => 'dev-test-app',
            'region' => 'us-east-1',
            'after_commit' => false,
        ]
    ],
];
```

**EmailJob.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Log;

class EmailJob extends Job
{
    public $queue;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->queue = $data['queue'];
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info('Email job '.$this->queue.' is run at start time - '.microtime(true));
    }
}
```

**SmsJob.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Log;

class SmsJob extends Job
{
    public $queue;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->queue = $data['queue'];
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info('Sms job '.$this->queue.' is run at start time - '.microtime(true));
    }
}
```

**Add to queues**

```
Queue::push(new EmailJob(array('queue' => 'email-test')));
Queue::push(new SmsJob(array('queue' => 'sms-test')));
```

How do I set the priorities (high, medium, low) for email, sms jobs etc... Might also add new jobs.

Answer (score 0):

SQS is the **Simple** Queue Service - unfortunately it has no built-in priority system.

You'd have to create multiple queues. The producer sends the message to the right queue (high, medium, low) and the consumer polls first for work in the high queue and works on that. If the high-queue is empty it polls the medium queue and if that's empty as well, the low queue.

Alternatively you can use Amazon MQ, which is managed ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ, both of which will most likely support this feature.

Comment: You mean multiple sqs services in aws

Comment: Multiple Queues in SQS, there is only one SQS service per region :)

Comment: I already have 1 queue in AWS SQS .. so should i create 3 queues for low, medium, high..   if so in that case how do i invoke using php artisan command

Comment: Yes, you'd have to create three Queues in SQS. I have no idea how to do that in php, I'm just here for SQS ;-)